# Issue using HTTP POST/PUT through no-ip

Tags: android, html, http, arduino

I have a project where I'm controlling an Arduino at my house using an Android app through WAN. I'm using MIT's App Inventor to design the app and with that I'm using a HTTP PUT/POST (I've tried both) to send the string of information "helloThere" to the Arduino. Everything has been fine while broadcasting directly to my IP address and port number. This is the Arduino output (I've obfusticated my IP and port):

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; GT-I9305 Build/KTU84P)
Host: xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 10

helloThere
```

The problem arises when I use a DDNS (no-ip) to refer to my IP address (As it is dynamic). For some reason the PUT/POST request does not get carried out when getting relayed through this. The output from the Arduino is shown below when using the DDNS:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; GT-I9305 Build/KTU84P)
Host: xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Somehow it is changing to a GET request instead of a PUT/POST, but it is still contacting the device. I'll be honest, I'm not a web guy so I'm pretty confused by this, is a DDNS not supposed to relay whatever you send to it? I've had a look around and can't find anything on this, any help or explanation would be appreciated.

EDIT: After doing a lot of further research I have figured out that a DDNS server actually returns the IP address of the desired hostname when queried. Does anyone have any idea what address and port that no ip use to do this? I am aware that windows uses an "NSLOOKUP" to perform this, but I have no idea how this is achieved on an arduino. It could be over UDP or HTTP. Again, any help from someone who has experience in this area would be appreciated.

Comment: Alright, finally solved the issue for those of you that are interested. Here's the Arduino code to retrieve the ip:

Answer (score 0):

Alright, finally solved the issue for those of you that are interested. Here's the Arduino code to retrieve the ip:

```
char server1[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.ddns.net"; //server to ping to get external
ip address
if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
previousMillis = currentMillis;
if (client1.connect(server1, 80)) { // if you get a connection output to
serial:
  Serial.println("connected");
  client1.println("GET / HTTP/1.0");  //Make a HTTP request:
  client1.println("Host: xxxxxxxxxxxx.ddns.net");
  client1.println("Connection: close");
  client1.println();
  delay(1200);
}
while (client1.available()) { //loop to read html from external server and
take ip from it
  char c = client1.read();
  HTTPArray [counter] = c; // copy all the data from the buffer into an
array
  counter++;
}
```